# Video conferencing with member-navigatable breakout rooms?

Tags: video-conferencing

As part of the Covid-19 pandemic, with San Francisco in lockdown, we'd like to bring a (previously offline) conference online; expected ~150 participants, for use of ~4 hours.

One of the features of the conference is participant-interest-driven breakouts; specifically, there are multiple tracks of presentations & discussions going on at the same time. Participants should be able to leave one & join another at any given time.

One way to solve this might be just running multiple videoconfing sessions at the same time; however, I feel that some people might have difficulty with following links & getting lost between switching slots.

The closest we have found so far is Zoom's "breakout rooms"; however, it requires the organizer to pre-arrange people into specific slots, as opposed to allowing the participant to choose their own story.

Are there any (high-qualilty, user-friendly) videoconferencing solutions currently, which allows seamless breakout rooms experience?